trying to get intuition into why Cross Entropy will always be greater or equal to the Entropy
I understand what entropy measures and cross entropy is the same except it is uses another distribution $q$ to compare it against $p.$ Is it because the log function is concave down so the predictions that are below the originals will grow larger negative then the ones above thus making always greater (after the negative)? Can someone help me understand why the cross entropy $-p_i\log_2(q_i)$ will always be bigger positive or equal to the entropy in a math sense?
$$\text{KL Divergence} = \text{Cross Entropy} - \text{Entropy}$$
$$D_\text{KL}(p\parallel q) = H(p,q) - H(p) $$
$$= -\sum_i p_i\log_2(q_i) - -\sum_i p_i \log_2(p_i)$$
$$= \sum_i -p_i\log_2(q_i) + \sum_i p_i \log_2(p_i)$$
$$D_\text{KL}(p\parallel q) = \sum_i p_i\log_2 \left(\frac{p_i}{q_i}\right)$$

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

View the expression $\sum_{i\,=\,1}^n p_i \log(p_i/q_i)$ as a function of $(q_1,\ldots,q_n)$ with $(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ fixed. You want to minimize this subject to the constraints $q_i\ge0$ for every $i$ and $q_1+\cdots+q_n=1.$
The gradient is the $n$-tuple $(-p_i/q_i)_{i\,=\,1}^n.$
The gradient of $q_1+\cdots+q_n$ is $(1,\ldots,1).$
So a Lagrange multiplier exists only when
$$
\frac{-p_1}{q_1} = \cdots = \frac{-p_n}{q_n}.
$$
Given the constraint, that means $q_i=p_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n.$
Notice that $\sum_i p_i\log(p_i/q_i) \to +\infty$ as $(q_i)_{i\,=\,1}^n$ approaches the boundary of the simplex. So the unique point in the interior where a Lagrange multiplier exists must be a minimum.

this is very concise by using constrained optimization. going through it now..
